# How to increment converted value in a label?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm working on a spriteKit game where I want an SKLabelNode to show the score. The score is an Int so I got this far:

```
var score = 0
var scoreLabelText = "\(score)"
```

I put this outside GameScne because if I do it inside it tells me Gamescene doesn't have a member named score.
In the `didBeginContact` function I then have this:

```
if firstBody.categoryBitMask == DropCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == GroundCategory {
        println(score)
        score++
```

I do see the score in the console but my label placed in `didMoveToView`

```
let scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(text: scoreLabelText)
    scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width - self.frame.width/8, self.frame.height - self.frame.height/8)
    addChild(scoreLabel)
```

doesn't update. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the score, but you do not change the scoreLabelText.  If you always want scoreLabelText to match the current string value of score, you might try using a property observer.

```
var scoreLabelText = "\(0)"
var score:Int = 0 { didSet { scoreLabelText = "\(score)" } }
```

Now anytime score changes, it should also change scoreLabelText.

Instead of having a property for scoreLabelText, why not make scoreLabel a property so you can access it.

```
var scoreLabel: SKLabelNode?
var score:Int = 0 { didSet { scoreLabel!.text = "\(score)" } }
```

then change

```
let scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(text: scoreLabelText)
```

to

```
scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "\(score)")
```

Or initialize the scoreLabel property in the definition, so it isn't an optional.

```
var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "\(0)")
var score:Int = 0 { didSet { scoreLabel.text = "\(score)" } }
```

then you can get rid of the later `scoreLabel = ....` and just position it and add it to the view.

Comment: It works because I see the scorelabelText updating in my println(). but the label doesn't change

Comment: Any idea of how to get the label from didmovetoview to update

Comment: It says SKLabelNode hasn't got a member named text.

Comment: sorry it is an optional, so you need to unwrap it `var score:Int = 0 { didSet { scoreLabel!.text = "\(score)" } }`

Answer (score 0):

You initialize scoreLabelText with the the initial score of 0, but never change it. scoreLabelText doesn't need to be a global variable, as it only exists to populate your scoreLabel, so define it in your scoreLabel setup and you will get the most recent score.

Answer (score 0):

`scoreLabelText` and `score` are two different variables. Each time you update `score`, you need to update `scoreLabelText` and then update your `scoreLabel.text`

```
if firstBody.categoryBitMask == DropCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == GroundCategory {
    println(score)
    score++
    scoreLabelText = "\(score)"
}
// Then you need to update your scoreLabel
```

The other solution is to use an observer to have your label automatically updated when you increment score:

```
let scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "0")
scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width - self.frame.width/8,   self.frame.height - self.frame.height/8)
addChild(scoreLabel)
var score:Int = 0 { didSet { scoreLabel.text = "\(score)" } }
```

Comment: But if the var score is in didmovetoview the didbegincontact doesn't find it.